# Using lodash to zip two objects with keys from one and values from the other

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have objects `A` and `B` like this:

```js
const A = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' };
const B = { a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb', c: 'ccc' };
```

I need to transform these two into an object with keys from A and values from B:

```js
{ foo: 'aaa', bar: 'bbb', baz: 'ccc' }
```

How can I do this with lodash?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the objects into pairs of `[key, value]`, flatten to a single array, then group by the 1st element (the original key), map the groups to an array of pairs, and convert back to an object.

Using lodash/fp:

```js
const { rest, flow, map, toPairs, flatten, groupBy, head, last, fromPairs } = _

const fn = rest(flow(
  map(toPairs), // map each object to pairs of [key, value]
  flatten, // flatten to a single array of pairs
  groupBy(head), // group the pairs by the key
  map(map(last)), // create a new pair by taking the last element of each pair in the group
  fromPairs // convert to an object
))

const A = { b: 'bar', c: 'baz', a: 'foo' }
const B = { a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb', c: 'ccc' }

const result = fn(A, B)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Using lodash:

```js
const { rest, flow, map, toPairs, flatten, groupBy, head, last, fromPairs } = _

const fn = rest(flow(
  objs => map(objs, toPairs), // map each object to pairs of [key, value]
  flatten, // flatten to a single array of pairs
  pairs => groupBy(pairs, head), // group the pairs by the key
  groups => map(groups, group => map(group, last)), // create a new pair by taking the last element of each pair in the group
  fromPairs // convert to an object
))

const A = { b: 'bar', c: 'baz', a: 'foo' }
const B = { a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb', c: 'ccc' }

const result = fn(A, B)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```